# Type on top of image interfering with hover state of image

Tags: jquery, css, image, types, hover

I'm totally lost on this. I'm trying to display the title of each of my projects in the center of the viewport when you hover over their respective images. I'm doing this through jQuery because it seems like the most straight forward way, but if there is an easier way then i'm all ears.

I've tried to add to the jQuery in order to keep the images from going back to full opacity when hovering over type and tried to find some kind of transparency attribute for the css of the "project-display-name" class to no avail.

I feel like its something very small or something very fundamental, but i'm not sure which. Anyone have any suggestions?

Any help is super appreciated!

here is a working demo of the problematic page, http://staging.lukasyonis.com/projects/allprojects.html

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.project').ready(function() {
        $(this).find('.project-display-name').hide();
    });

    $('.project').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.project-display-name').fadeIn(100);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.project-display-name').fadeOut(125);
    });

    $('.project-link').hover(function() {
        $(this).data('title', $(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('title'));
    });
});
```

```css
#buttons {
 z-index:11;
 position:fixed;
 float:left;
 bottom:0;
 margin-bottom:1.75em;
 display:inline;
}


#buttons ul li { 
 list-style-type:none;
 display:inline;
 color: #000;
 line-height:1.25em; 
 text-align:left;
 float:left;
    font-family: "apercuregular", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:100%;
}

#buttons li#next {
 float:right;
}


#buttons ul li a {
 display:block;
} 


#thumbnail {
 margin-top:6.5em;
}

#thumbnail img {
 margin-bottom:1%;
 margin-left:3%;
 width:97%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#thumbnail img:last-of-type {
 margin-bottom:0;
}

#copy #head {
 font-family:"apercuregular", Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height:1.25em;
}

#copy #sub {
 font-family:"aperculight_italic", Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height:1.25em;
}


#copy #bold {
 font-family:"aperculight", Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height:1.25em;
} 

#copy {
 position:fixed;
 margin-top:6.5em;
 font-family:"aperculight", Helvetica, Arial;
 line-height:1.25em;
 margin-left: 1.75em;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}


#project-container {
 margin-top:6.5em;
}

#project01 img, #project02 img, #project03 img, #project04 img, #project05 img, #project06 img, #project07 img, #project08 img {
 transition:opacity .3s ease;
 opacity: 1;
}

#project01 img:hover, #project02 img:hover, #project03 img:hover, #project04 img:hover, #project05 img:hover, #project06 img:hover, #project07 img:hover, #project08 img:hover, .project-display-name:hover {
 opacity: .3;
}

.project:hover .project-display-name {
 opacity: 1;
}

.project-display-name {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 10000000;
 font-family: "fugueregular", Helvetica, Arial;
 font-size:7em;
 line-height: 1.125em;
 text-align: center;
 color: #000;
 width: 90%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s; 
}
 
#project01 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;      
}


#project02 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
    -webkit-animation
}

#project03 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#project04 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#project05 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}


#project06 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 margin-bottom:3.75%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}


#project07 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#project08 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
 -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 1s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 1s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 1s;
}

#project09 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
}

#project10 img {
 z-index:100;
 width:100%;
}



@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="section d-show d-showgrid">

    <header id="header" class="d-all box">
        <span id="inner-head" class="d-all box">
                        <article id="logomark" class="d1 box">
                            <a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/LogoBlue_x2.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
                        </article>


                        <article id="menu" class="d10-d12 box">
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li id="practice"><a href="../practice.html">profile</a></li>
                                <li id="past"><a href="allprojects.html">work</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </article>
                    </span>
    </header>

    <article id="project-container" class="d-all box">
        <article id="project01" class="d1-d6 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2014/art-science.html' title='The Art &amp; Science Series'>
                <img src="../images/work/2014/art-science/Scene_02.jpg" alt="art-science" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>forum studio:
                        <br />the art &amp; science series</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project02" class="d7-d12 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2014/shadia-ghantous.html' title='Shadia Ghantous'>
                <img src="../images/work/2014/shadia-ghantous/Scene_08.jpg" alt="shadia" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>shadia ghantous</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project03" class="d1-d6 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2014/gojo.html' title='Gojo Contractors and Developers'>
                <img src="../images/work/2014/gojo/Scene_04.jpg" alt="gojo" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>gojo contractors and developers</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project04" class="d7-d12 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2013/arkitekt.html' title='Arkitekt 29'>
                <img src="../images/work/2013/arkitekt/Scene_02a.jpg" alt="arkitekt" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>arkitekt 29</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project05" class="d1-d6 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2012/mayday.html' title='May Day 2012'>
                <img src="../images/work/2012/mayday/Scene_01.jpg" alt="mayday" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>may day 2012</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project06" class="d7-d12 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2014/lukasyonis.html' title='Lukas Yonis'>
                <img src="../images/work/2014/lukasyonis/Scene_11.jpg" alt="lukasyonis" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>lukas yonis</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project07" class="d1-d6 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2012/eternals.html' title='The Eternals Espiritu Zombi Group at The Hideout'>
                <img src="../images/work/2012/eternals/Scene_01.jpg" alt="eternals" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>the eternals espiritu zombi group at the hideout</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project08" class="d7-d12 box project">
            <a class="project-link" href='2013/rarariot.html' title='Ra Ra Riot at Metro Chicago'>
                <img src="../images/work/2013/rarariot/Scene_01.jpg" alt="rarariot" />
                <figcaption class="project-display-name">
                    <p>ra ra riot at metro chicago</p>
                </figcaption>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article id="project09" class="d1-d6 box project">

        </article>
    </article>
```

Comment: Your demo doesn't match your code anymore. Could you update your question explaining what your immediate problem is?

Comment: I'm not sure why that is..I'm using Gridset to manage my grid system and I didnt include that, so maybe that is breaking everything. I'll try and add that and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if I understand you're problem right, but try to use this:

```
.project-display-name, .project-display-name p {
     pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Comment: I think this may be what i'm looking for! My main problem was that the type on top of the images was interfering with the hover state of the images (which takes the opacity of the image to 30%), essentially turning off the hover state when your cursor is over the type.

It looks like this alleviates the problem in a pretty simple way though – thanks so much!!